# How do I use system("chcp 936") in my dialog based project?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, unicode, chinese-locale

The code below is supposed to convert a wstring "！" to a string and output it,

```
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Chinese_China.936");
    //system("chcp 936"); 
    
    std::wstring ws = L"！";
    string as((ws.length()) * sizeof(wchar_t), '-');
    auto rs = wcstombs((char*)as.c_str(), ws.c_str(), as.length());
    as.resize(rs);
    cout << rs << ":" << as << endl;
```

If you run it without `system("chcp 936");`, the converted string is "£¡" rather than "！". If with `system("chcp 936");`, the result is correct in a console project.

[image]

But on my Dialog based project, `system("chcp 936")`is useless, even if it's workable, I can't use it, because it would popup a console.

[image]

PS: the IDE is Visual Studio 2019, and my source code is stored as in UTF-8 with signature.
My operation system language is English and language for non-unicode programs is English (United States).

[image]

Edit: it's interesting, even with "en-US" locale, "！" can be converted to an ASCII "!".

[image]

But I don't get where "£¡" I got in the dialog based project.

Comment: Programs should read and accomodate the user's locale.  They should not force their own locale on the user.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: this should be helpful to understand what is the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67819605/1387438

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two distinct points to considere with locales:

- you must tell the program what charset should be used when converting unicode characters to plain bytes (this is the role for `setlocale`)
- you must tell the *terminal* what charset it should render (this is the role for `chcp` in Windows console)

The first point depends on the language and optionaly libraries that you use in your program (here the C++ language and Standard Library)

The second point depends on the *console* application and underlying system. Windows console uses `chcp`, and you will find in that [other post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/116404/105306) how you can configure `xterm` in a Unix-like system.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the cause, the wstring-to-string conversion is no problem, the problem was I used [CA2T](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ca2wex-class?view=msvc-170) to convert the Chinese punctuation mark and it failed. So it showed "£¡" in the UI finally.

By means of `mbstowcs`, the counterpart of `wcstombs`, it would work.

[image]