# Converting shift-jis encoded file to to utf-8 in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, character-encoding, shift-jis

I am trying with below code to convert from shift-jis file to utf-8, but when we open the output file it has corrupted characters, looks like something is missed out here, any thoughts?

```
// From file
FILE* shiftJisFile = _tfopen(lpszShiftJs, _T("rb"));
int nLen = _filelength(fileno(shiftJisFile));
LPSTR lpszBuf = new char[nLen];
fread(lpszBuf, 1, nLen, shiftJisFile);

// convert multibyte to  wide char
int utf16size = ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, lpszBuf, -1, 0, 0);
LPWSTR pUTF16 = new WCHAR[utf16size];
::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, lpszBuf, -1, pUTF16, utf16size);

wstring str(pUTF16);

// convert wide char to multi byte utf-8 before writing to a file
fstream File("filepath", std::ios::out);
string result = string();
result.resize(WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, str.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0, 0, 0));
char* ptr = &result[0];
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, str.c_str(), -1, ptr, result.size(), 0, 0);
File << result;

File.close();
```

Comment: Also, how are you viewing the file afterwards. I suspect the file is valid, but you're then opening it in notepad or the console, and those are displaying the file wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems.

The first problem is that when you are *writing* the output file, you need to set it to `binary` for the same reason you need to do so when reading the input.

```
fstream File("filepath", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
```

The second problem is that when you are *reading* the input file, you are only reading the bytes of the input stream and treat them like a string. However, those bytes do not have a terminating null character. If you call `MultiByteToWideChar` with a `-1` length, it infers the input string length from the terminating null character, which is missing in your case. That means both `utf16size` and the contents of  `pUTF16` are *already wrong*. Add it manually after reading the file:

```
int nLen = _filelength(fileno(shiftJisFile));
LPSTR lpszBuf = new char[nLen+1];
fread(lpszBuf, 1, nLen, shiftJisFile);
lpszBuf[nLen] = 0;
```

The last problem is that you are using `CP_ACP`. That means "the current code page". In your question, you were specifically asking how to convert *Shift-JIS*. The code page Windows uses for its closes equivalent to what is commonly called "Shift-JIS" is `932` (you can look that up on wikipedia for example). So use `932` instead of `CP_ACP`:

```
int utf16size = ::MultiByteToWideChar(932, 0, lpszBuf, -1, 0, 0);
LPWSTR pUTF16 = new WCHAR[utf16size];
::MultiByteToWideChar(932, 0, lpszBuf, -1, pUTF16, utf16size);
```

Additionally, there is no reason to create `wstring str(pUTF16)`. Just use `pUTF16` directly in the `WideCharToMultiByte` calls.

Also, I'm not sure how kosher `char *ptr = &result[0]` is. I personally would not create a string specifically as a buffer for this.

Here is the corrected code. I would personally not write it this way, but I don't want to impose my coding ideology on you, so I made only the changes necessary to fix it:

```
// From file
FILE* shiftJisFile = _tfopen(lpszShiftJs, _T("rb"));
int nLen = _filelength(fileno(shiftJisFile));
LPSTR lpszBuf = new char[nLen+1];
fread(lpszBuf, 1, nLen, shiftJisFile);
lpszBuf[nLen] = 0;

// convert multibyte to  wide char
int utf16size = ::MultiByteToWideChar(932, 0, lpszBuf, -1, 0, 0);
LPWSTR pUTF16 = new WCHAR[utf16size];
::MultiByteToWideChar(932, 0, lpszBuf, -1, pUTF16, utf16size);

// convert wide char to multi byte utf-8 before writing to a file
fstream File("filepath", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
string result;
result.resize(WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, pUTF16, -1, NULL, 0, 0, 0));
char *ptr = &result[0];
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, pUTF16, -1, ptr, result.size(), 0, 0);
File << ptr;

File.close();
```

Also, you have a memory leak -- `lpszBuf` and `pUTF16` are not cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

You should try use `std::locale` to perform this conversion:

```cpp
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

void convert(const fs::path inName, const fs::path outName)
{
    std::wifstream in{inName};
    in.imbue(std::locale{".932"}); // or "ja_JP.SJIS"
    if (in) {
        std::wofstream out{outName};
        out.imbue(std::locale{".utf-8"});
        
        std::wstring line;
        while (getline(in, line)) {
            out << line << L'\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Note locale names are platform specific - I think I used proper one for Windows.
**Update:** I've tested this on my Window 10 machine with MSVC 19.29.30145 and works perfectly. I used [wiki page](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E) to get some valid Japanese text and used Notepad++ to save this text in proper encoding (Shift-JIS).

I also used Beyond Compare to verify results:
[image: Beyond Compare Window]

Note I used similar method [here for Korean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67819605/1387438) and it worked nicely.

Answer (score -1):

`wstring str(pUTF16);` - `pUTF16` there does not end with zero char. It should be `wstring str(pUTF16, utf16size);`