# Convert UTF-8 string containing accented character to UTF-16

Tags: c++, string, unicode, utf-8, c++17

I'm trying to convert `std::string` which contains some accented character to `std::wstring` as explained in [C++ Convert string (or char*) to wstring (or wchar_t*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573834/c-convert-string-or-char-to-wstring-or-wchar-t), but my program throws **bad conversion** exception.

I'm on Windows 10 and using MSVC 2022 v17.4.1, with language set to C++17.

Here is a minimal reproducible program which demonstrate the issue:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>

#pragma warning( disable : 4996  )

int main()
{
    std::string s{ "hello ê world" };
    
    try {
        std::wstring ws = std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>>().from_bytes(s);
        std::wcout << ws << "\n";
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Any help in converting the above `std::string` to `std::wstring` is highly appreciated.

Comment: "*`std::string s{ "hello ê world" };`*" This is not necessarily encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: If you are going to be dealing with unicode and different text encodings I recommend using a library like ICU instead.  Do note that `std::codecvt_utf8` was deprecated in C++17.

Comment: If you want to test your code I suggest you explicitly initialise your string with the correct byte sequence. There is absolutely no guarantee that a string literal in your source code is encoded in UTF-8

Comment: So something like `"hello \xC3\xAA world"`, C3 AA being the correct UTF-8 byte sequence for lower case e with circumflex.

Comment: If it still fails with that string then ask again.

Comment: @john `"hello \xC3\xAA world"` does work, I get the output as `hello Ω world`. In my case I receive the string input from the user, how can I make sure that the input byte stream in encoded in UTF-8 format?

Comment: @NicolBolas, how can I make sure that the string is encoded in UTF-8 format?

Comment: This migth be helpful to understand what happens: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67819605/1387438 basically your encoding is inconsistent in one of the steps: source code, compilation, executable, global locale configuration. Note that MSVC prefer to use your system locale which is usually not UTF-8 but some county specific one byte encoding.

Comment: @Aamir "*how can I make sure that the input byte stream in encoded in UTF-8 format?*" - it depends on how you are receiving the input to begin with, which you did not show.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I use `wxTextCtrl` from wxWidgets GUI library to get input from the user. Apart from normal ASCII characters, user can enter accented characters as input, which I need to convert to `wstring`.

Comment: @Aamir [`wxTextCtrl`](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_text_ctrl.html) provides text to you as a [`wxString`](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_string.html), which is a native Unicode string that is convertible to `std::wstring` without data loss (see [`wxString::ToStdWstring()`](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_string.html#acd4ba44e34428aa83cd9922d2933d060)). So, why are you trying to convert the text to a UTF-8 `std::string` and then to a UTF-16 `std::wstring`? Just let the text handle the UTF-16 conversion for you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I don’t receive the wxString directly, wxString is passed as std::string to different C++ library before received by my function.

Comment: @Aamir ok, well, even so, `wxString` can be converted to UTF-8 using [`wxString::utf8_str()`](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_string.html#ad71e3ded85939db8af9eeadfa02719ac), which can then be used to construct a `std::string`, so there is no reason for you to have a `std::string` that is not valid UTF-8 for `std::wstring_convert` to decode.

Comment: "I receive the string input from the user, how can I make sure that the input byte stream in encoded in UTF-8 format?" It's a separate, completely different question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to both build with the `/utf-8` compiler flag and save your file as UTF-8.

To save a file as UTF-8 in Visual Studio, select "Save with Encoding..." from the "Save As" dialog.

[image: Save As dialog]

Your string is probably being read in as "hello Ãª world" or another non-UTF-8 string in another codepage.

From the [Visual Studio documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8?view=msvc-170):

> If no byte-order mark is found, it assumes that the source file is encoded in the current user code page, unless you've specified a code page by using `/utf-8` or the `/source-charset` option.