# How to Store Emojis in char8_t and Print Them Out in C++20?

Tags: c++, utf-8, c++20, emoji, utf

I just now heard about the existence of `char8_t`, `char16_t` and `char32_t` and I am testing it out. When I try to compile the code below, `g++` throws the following error:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, char32_t) [with _Traits = char_traits<char>]’
    6 |         std::cout << U'' << std::endl;
      |                      ^~~~~
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  char32_t c = U'';

  std::cout << c << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Additionally, why can't I put the emoji into a `char8_t` or `char16_t`? For example, the following lines of code don't work:

```cpp
char16_t c1 = u'';
char8_t c2 = u8'';
auto c3 = u'';
auto c4 = u8'';
```

From my understanding, emojis are UTF-8 characters and should therefore fit into a `char8_t`.

Comment: characters encoded in utf-8 can be more than 1 byte. And that's definitely the case for emojis

Comment: This is just problem of encoding. Which compiler are you using and what on platform?

Comment: Use `char const* c = "";`

Comment: Here is similar problem where I explain how to handle this on MSVC: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67819605/1387438 Note that if you are suing Windows and MinGW, then support of locale is poor. On other platforms implicit use of UTF-8 should make this work quite easily.

Comment: There's not enough space in a `uint8_t` to contain all the ASCII characters and all the emoji's.  You'll need a data structure with more space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> emojis are UTF-8 characters

There is no such thing as a "UTF-8 character".

There are Unicode codepoints. These can be represented in the UTF-8 encoding, such that each codepoint maps to a sequence of one or more UTF-8 code units: `char8_t`s. But that means that most codepoints map to multiple `char8_t`s: AKA, a string. And Emojis are not among the 127 codepoints that map to a single UTF-8 code unit.

Emoji in particular can be built out of *multiple* codepoints, so even using UTF-32, you cannot guarantee that any emoji could be stored in a single `char32_t` codepoint.

It's best to treat these things as strings, not characters, at all times. Forget that "characters" even exist.

Answer (score 4):

**Code**

- Tested in Visual C++ using [Windows Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/install).
  https://github.com/JomaStackOverflowAnswers/EmojiCpp20
- GCC https://godbolt.org/z/cMbeoGf9a
- Clang https://godbolt.org/z/EhfdaM61x

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#ifdef _WIN32 
#include <Windows.h>
#define SET_CONSOLE_UTF8 SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8); SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8); //Set console output to UTF-8.Visual C++ code on Windows.
#endif // _WIN32 


#if defined(__cpp_char8_t) | defined(__cpp_lib_char8_t)

//Operator <<
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::u8string& str)
{
    os << reinterpret_cast<const char*>(str.data());
    return os;
}

//Convert u8string to string.
std::string ToString(const std::u8string& s) {
    return std::string(s.begin(), s.end());
}

std::u8string Tou8String(const std::string& s) {
    return std::u8string(s.begin(), s.end());
}

//const char8_t* literal to string. Operator ""_s
static inline std::string operator"" _s(const char8_t* value, size_t size) {
    static std::string x(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(value), size);
    return x;
}

#endif


using namespace std::string_literals;// operator ""s

int main() {
#ifdef _WIN32
    SET_CONSOLE_UTF8
#endif

    std::u8string u8String = u8""s;// u8string literal.
    std::string str = u8""_s; //Operator "_s". Convert utf8 literal(const char8_t*) to std::string. 

    std::cout << "string              " << str << std::endl; //Using operator << for std::string
    std::cout << "u8string -> string  " << ToString(u8String) << std::endl; //Using function ToString(u8string) -> string
    std::cout << "u8string            " << u8String << std::endl; //Using operator << for std::u8string.
    std::cout << "string -> u8string  " << Tou8String(str) << std::endl; //Using function Tou8String(string) -> u8string

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output Windows Terminal and https://godbolt.org/(Clang and GCC)**

```
string              
u8string -> string  
u8string            
string -> u8string
```

[image: VisualC++]

[image: godbolt - CLANG]

[image: GCC]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question Screenshots to godbolt pages is sick. You should share a link to godbolt, then anyone can play with it. Note that godbolt implicitly uses UTF-8 encoding. This doesn't have to be default on real systems.

Answer (score 2):

> When I try to compile the code below, g++ throws the following error:

The encoding expected by the narrow and wide standard streams is implementation-dependent and may also depend on what the terminal you are ultimately printing to expects. You need to convert your character to the correct encoding as either `char` or `wchar_t` type if you want to print to `std::cout` or `std::wcout` respectively.

> Additionally, why can't I put the emoji into a char8_t or char16_t? For example, the following lines of code don't work:

The emoji is unicode code point U+1F60B which in both UTF-8 and UTF-16 encoding requires multiple code units. But you are trying to form a *character literal*, which holds only *one* code unit.

> From my understanding, emojis are UTF-8 characters [...]

That doesn't make sense. UTF-8 is an encoding for unicode code points. It doesn't make sense to say that a character "is UTF-8". This shows that you might have fundamental misunderstandings on how Unicode and character/string encodings in general work. I would suggest you read some introduction on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

This works

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  const char* c = "";

  std::cout << c << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Explanation.

1. is a multibyte sequence and does not fit in a single `char`. Thus `const char*` should be used.
2. The default source file encoding is UTF-8, thus Unicode chars can be used only in UTF-8 encoding. For `char32_t` it should be written as `U'\x1F60B'`.
3. `operator<<(std::basic_ostream)` is deleted for `char8_t`, `char16_t` and `char32_t`.

Comment: On Windows it will not work out of the box, since system usually uses country specific one byte encodings, where there is no full Unicode support.

Comment: "*The default source file encoding is UTF-8*" For which compiler?

Comment: @NicolBolas on Linux gcc and clang are using UTF-8  implicitly.

Comment: @MarekR Just tried  in VS and it offered to save a file in UTF-8 with a BOM. So, this is not an issue.

Comment: auto also support this ;)
https://godbolt.org/z/97b1exsc7

Comment: @273K it depends on you machine settings. If you configured your machine to use code page 65001 (UTF-8) this will work out of the box. I'm currently using codpeage 437 (or 1252) and outcome on my console is `≡ƒÿï`. I have to add `std::locale::global(std::locale(".utf-8")); std::cout.imbue(std::locale(""));` to make it work and change console code page to something what supports this character (`chcp 65001`).