# Why is the emoji displays incorrectly in Windows Terminal?

Tags: c++, emoji, windows-terminal

I try to use C++ to output a emoji and below is the code. I wrote this in VS Code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "";
    return 0;
}
```

Then I try to compile this code with Clang++ and get a .exe file. But when I run the .exe file in Windows Terminal it doesn't display correctly.

Below is what I get when I run the file.

```
PS C:\Users\26354> D:\Code_exercise\Assignment\Class\Bin\Temp.exe
馃槉
```

PS:

Clang version 13.0.1

Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc

Windows Terminal Version: 1.12.10393.0

VS Code Version: 1.64.2

Windows Version: Windows 10 Pro 21H2

Comment: Which codepage does your terminal use when launching your application?

Comment: Windows PowerShell

Comment: Type `chcp` and tell us what you get.

Comment: That’s your problem then. Type `chcp 65001` and run your program again. 

Comment: I got : `活动代码页: 936`

Comment: Similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70087913/1387438